# Iterating over a list of booleans values

Tags: netlogo

**I have a list called ( a) which holds booleans values thus I want to implement an if statement if each item value in the list ( a  )is true and implement another if statement if each item value in list ( a) is false.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

I tried this but it does not work !!! 
1- foreach a [ x -> if ( x = true) [ask pharmacists  [ do the first if statment ] 
2-  foreach a [ x -> if ( x = false) [ask pharmacists  [ do the second if statment ]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

I want to cycle at each boolean value in list (a) and perform an if statement based on whether the value is true or false.**

Comment: How is this question any different from the one you asked yesterday and have now apparently deleted? What's more, Luke has given you an answer that is pretty similar to the answer I gave to yesterday's question. If you are trying to provide more information, then please edit the question rather than delete it. You are wasting both my time and Luke's by asking the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do- you may want to have a look at the [Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidelines. Note the comment:

> DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Also, have a look at the section on making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help users provide you with a useful answer that is definitely applicable to your issue. If my answer below is not helpful, I suggest you make a toy model that acts as a working example of the problem you're running into.

---

If you just want to iterate over a list of `true` / `false` values, I think you're on the right track- have a look at the very simple example below which just prints a statement depending on whether the current iterated value is `true` or `false`:

```
to setup
  ca

  let boolean-list [ true true true false true false false false ]

  foreach boolean-list [ 
    i ->
    ifelse i [
      print "Current item is true!"
    ] [
      print "Current item is false!"
    ]
  ]

  reset-ticks
end
```

Comment: I will consider your remarks above for asking any further questions thanks a lot.